# RxJava callback

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm reading a book named "RxJava Essentials". Following code is from there. and i modified a little.

I have called `refreshList()` in `OnCreate` of my `Activity`. and `subscriber.onNext()` has been called many times in `getApps()` and `subscriber.onCompleted()` has been called. After that `onNext` callbak (implemented in `refreshList()`) has been called. `public void onNext(List<AppInfo> appInfos)`

I wander why `onNext()` callback is not called when `subscriber.onNext()` actuall called? Why it has been called later?

```
void refreshList()
{
    getApps().toSortedList()
    .subscribe(new Observer<List<AppInfo>>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCompleted()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable te) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<AppInfo> appInfos) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onNext()");

            for (AppInfo tmpInfo : appInfos)
            {
                //tmpInfo.toString();
                Log.e(TAG, String.format("tmpInfo = %s", tmpInfo.toString()));
            }
        }
    });
}


private Observable<AppInfo> getApps()
{
    return Observable.create(subscriber ->
    {
        List<AppInfoRich> apps = new ArrayList<>();

        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo info : infos)
        {
            apps.add(new AppInfoRich(this, info));
        }

        for (AppInfoRich appInfo : apps)
        {
            Bitmap icon = BitmapUtils.drawableToBitmap(appInfo.getIcon());
            String name = appInfo.getName();
            String iconPath = mFilesDir + "/" + name;

            //BitmapUtils.storeBitmap(App.instance, icon, name);

            BitmapUtils.storeBitmap(getApplicationContext(), icon, name);

            if(subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
            {
                return;
            }

            subscriber.onNext(new AppInfo(name, iconPath, appInfo.getLastUpdateTime()));

        }

        if( !subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't subscribe directly to the observable you have created. You are subscribing to the result of the [toSortedList operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toSortedList()), which collects all emitted items into a list, sorts it, and then emits the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.